# Unable to export to archive file "Access is denied" in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, export

I'm trying to export my school's homework assignment to an archive using the eclipse export wizard.  Per my instructors directions, I named the zip folder H01 but when a click "Finish" I get this error:

> Export error.  H01.zip (Access is denied).

How would I go about fixing this?

I tried looking at the security properties of many folders/files such as the eclipse-workspace or the individual files in the project.  Also freshly installed eclipsed and re-did my entire assignment.

https://gyazo.com/92b28ffde24c146fc1a9dfdbf590ada4

TLDR; I would like to archive this project to a file called `H01.zip`, but I get an error that says `Access is denied`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The path I was using to save the zip file was C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2 but you are unable (even to an administrator) to directly edit this directory.  I simply changed the path to be a destination that I had permissions to edit.  You can check if you are able to edit a file by right clicking -> properties -> security.